# CSS grid - calculated responsive layout overflows fixed-width parent container

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a 1x4up grid layout that works great until I try to wrap it in a centered container div. Here is a Pen with the layout.

https://codepen.io/kirkbross/pen/XWEBRWw

I tried using @media queries for the var --fw, first setting it to 1320px, then 100vw at < 1320px, but all the other calculated variables don't take kindly to that approach. Thoughts?

The result should be the grid layout centered within 1320px parent, and begins shrinking responsively when the window hits 1319px.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  --fw: 100vw;
  --w1: calc((var(--fw) - 40px + (var(--ratio) * 10px)) / 2);
  /* the width of the big rectangle */
  --ratio: calc(678 / 399);
  --h1: calc(var(--w1) / var(--ratio));
  /* the height of the big rectangle */
  --h: calc((var(--h1) - 10px) / 2);
  /* the height and width of the smaller rectangles */
  --w: calc(var(--h) * var(--ratio));
  display: inline-grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "A B C" "A D E";
  grid-template-columns: var(--w1) var(--w) var(--w);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 10px black;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-container>div {
  height: var(--h);
  width: var(--w);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(1) {
  width: var(--w1);
  height: var(--h1);
  grid-area: A;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: B;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: C;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: D;
}

.grid-container> :nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: E;
}
```

```html
/* this 1320px wrapper div breaks layout until the window is shrunk to the wrapper width*/

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "*...all the other calculated variables don't take kindly to that approach*" - in what way do they react to the approach using media queries? I didn't see that line on my first reading, but in my posted answer that approach seems to work perfectly well, what problems have you observed?

Comment: Ii don't understand what you are aiming for when you are on a viewport wider than 1320px. You constrain the wrapper to be 1320px but the container inside it has 100vw width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that the approach using a media query is the correct way to go, in order to modify the `--fw` custom property of the `.grid-container` to fit the circumstances of the current display:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1320px) {
  .grid-container {
    --fw: 1320px;
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  --fw: 100vw;
  --w1: calc((var(--fw) - 40px + (var(--ratio) * 10px)) / 2);
  /* the width of the big rectangle */
  --ratio: calc(678 / 399);
  --h1: calc(var(--w1) / var(--ratio));
  /* the height of the big rectangle */
  --h: calc((var(--h1) - 10px) / 2);
  /* the height and width of the smaller rectangles */
  --w: calc(var(--h) * var(--ratio));
  display: inline-grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "A B C""A D E";
  grid-template-columns: var(--w1) var(--w) var(--w);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 10px black;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-container > div {
  height: var(--h);
  width: var(--w);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(1) {
  width: var(--w1);
  height: var(--h1);
  grid-area: A;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: B;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: C;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: D;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: E;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1320px) {
  .grid-container {
    --fw: 1320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code I've chosen to target the screens on displays that are wider than `1320px` since that appears to be the breakpoint you're targeting. It's entirely possible to reverse that, and instead target displays smaller than `1320px`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .grid-container {
    --fw: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Of course this would require that the custom property be set to:

```
--fw: 1320px
```

In the 'non-queried' code.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  --fw: 1320px;
  --w1: calc((var(--fw) - 40px + (var(--ratio) * 10px)) / 2);
  /* the width of the big rectangle */
  --ratio: calc(678 / 399);
  --h1: calc(var(--w1) / var(--ratio));
  /* the height of the big rectangle */
  --h: calc((var(--h1) - 10px) / 2);
  /* the height and width of the smaller rectangles */
  --w: calc(var(--h) * var(--ratio));
  display: inline-grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "A B C""A D E";
  grid-template-columns: var(--w1) var(--w) var(--w);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 10px black;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-container > div {
  height: var(--h);
  width: var(--w);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(1) {
  width: var(--w1);
  height: var(--h1);
  grid-area: A;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: B;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: C;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: D;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: E;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .grid-container {
    --fw: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/678/399">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out the Pen now. I'm realizing that while the parent width is effectively 1320px, it's actually 1440px with 60px L/R padding. To make matters more complicated, the wrapper L/R padding changes to a percentage at < 1200px.